# Is a loop (in graph theory) considered adjacent to itself?

Tags: graph-theory

Is a loop (in graph theory) considered adjacent to itself? Neither my textbook nor pure math associates seem to have a sure answer. for example:: in an exercise, there is a graph displayed containing a vertex v with a loop e, and other edges incident on v. The question asks, which edges are adjacent to e?

Comment: @DonThousand, you did not read the question carefully.

Comment: Discrete Mathematics with Applications; Epp.

Comment: It depends how adjacent edges are defined. If the definition is that edges $e$ and $f$ are adjacent if they have a common vertex, then a loop is adjacent to itself, but then every edge is also adjacent to itself. If $e\neq f$ is required, then loops aren't adjacent to themselves.

Comment: "then every edge is adjacent to itself" is obviously not a valid idea. Loops count for degree 2, if it matters here.

Comment: @GoranMalic Yet another definition of adjacent edges would make loops the only edges that are adjacent to themselves. An edge is composed of two half-edges. The degree of a vertex $v$ is the number of half-edges incident with $v$. Two half-edges are adjacent if they are distinct and incident with the same vertex. Two edges $e$ and $f$ are adjacent if some half-edge of $e$ is adjacent to some half-edge of $f$.

Comment: It can be supposed that *adjacent* is defined for edges in a way that corresponds to whether or not they form a trail. With that, a loop is adjacent to all *other* edges incident with its sole end vertex, but not with itself. If we replace "trail" with "walk", then a loop *is* adjacent to itself - just as every edge is adjacent to itself. -- In the end, this distinction is equivalent to what Goran Malic wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal definition in my textbook is "Two edges are adjacent if they are both incident on the same vertex."  As seems clear both in this definition and in the comments, we are agreed that this is an irreflexive relation.  Since all loops are edges, our agreement is therefore that a loop cannot be adjacent to itself.

If your follow-up question is "Loops are a special sort of edge; will this harsh definition of adjacency cause us headaches as we continue to study graph theory?" -- I can't recall any point where it ever does in practice.